# Are there local boat operators that go to Cies Islands?

Tags: transportation, spain, ferries, price, islands

I am looking for ways to get to visit Cies Islands in Galicia, Spain.

I Googled and found one boat operator. I am wondering if there are other options like smaller operators, or is it a monopoly or concession?

If there are more, how easy is it to buy the ticket on the spot and how much should I expect to pay? Do they often sell out?

I can leave from any place along the coast.

Comment: It would be better to have some more details, or you'll end up with answers like "Swimming from Melide is free" or "You can walk from neighbourin Faro Island, since the departure is not important"

Comment: Questions about price shopping are specifically off topic. See [help]

Comment: Changed it to be on topic

Answer (score 3):

> **How to get to Cíes**
>
> Do you want to know how get to the Cíes Islands? The only way to access the Cíes is by sea. In summer and Easter, there are [several shipping companies based in the port of Vigo](http://www.turismodevigo.org/en/node/2321) that carry out daily boat tours to the Cíes. These ferries will take you straight to the islands of Monte Agudo and O Faro.
>
> The Cíes have a limit of 2,200 visitors a day, so it’s advisable to book a place on the boat in advance.
>
> The third island, San Martiño, is only accessible by private boat, which is also the only way to access the archipelago the rest of the year. Remember that an [anchoring permit](http://www.iatlanticas.es/html/index96e7.html) for your boat is mandatory in the Cíes.
>
> If you decide to [rent a boat in Vigo](http://www.turismodevigo.org/en/node/752) to visit the Cíes, check the services offered by the different companies that rent boats and enjoy an unforgettable cruise along the [Vigo estuary](http://www.turismodevigo.org/en/node/2306).